# How to connect juju with microk8s cluster

Tags: microk8s, juju

I deploymented one Microk8s cluster with 4 metal bare machines how you can see above:

```
NAME                      STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION
p-br-pr-cta-gt2-mk8s-01   Ready    <none>   3h31m   v1.28.3
p-br-pr-cta-gt2-mk8s-04   Ready    <none>   104m    v1.28.3
p-br-pr-cta-gt2-mk8s-02   Ready    <none>   104m    v1.28.3
p-br-pr-cta-gt2-mk8s-03   Ready    <none>   3h31m   v1.28.3


My version of Microk8s is: v1.28.3.
My version of juju is: 3.1.6
```

I want to manager my Microk8s cluster with Juju... but I dont no kown how to connect on cluster...

Does anyone use this same solution, if so could you share how it was done?

Tks,

Paulo